# How to replace an HTML element while keeping the position of all other elements on the page the same

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

Let's say you're on a third party webpage and so you have no control over the page, except for your javascript.

You want to replace an element with an empty DOM node, but you want the page to maintain the same positioning for all other elements on the page. You don't know what the element will be and what the styles are on the webpage.

If you replace the element with a DIV, and you manually set the width and the height of that div to be the same as the replaced element, then you are almost there. However, you would not know if there are any other styling on the page that would apply to the DIV and mess things up. Also, if the replaced element was floated to the left or right, or was `display:inline`, then replacing it with a DIV might mess up the position of other elements on the page.

Is there a foolproof way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing the whole element, you could just throw away its content. However, it could still have borders and background images, not to mention event handlers like mouseover, so there are plenty of awkward cases.

Comment: yeah I thought about this, but what if it's an image? I would need to have some kind of overriding inline styles or something in addition to removing attributes.

Comment: Why not just set `visibility: hidden` on the element? That will maintain the layout, and just make it invisible.

Comment: unfortunately I can't do this for specific reasons